# Нажать checkbox с опомщью Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, веб-скрейпинг

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, ' _loop_primary_checkbox').click()
```

Вот код чекбокса, пробовал найти его и через имя класса и через название, и через xpath

````
<input _ngcontent-c1="" class=" _loop_primary_checkbox" name="srchwtn" title="Check here to select document for download" type="checkbox" value="facetsResponse[facetItems][innerFacetIdObject].label">```

Выдает следующую ошибку:
Exception has occurred: InvalidSelectorException
Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
````